# QML: how to add scrollbar into ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, scrollbar

I have a simple ListView program and therein trying to attach scrollbar. There is no movement on list while scrolling up/ down, here, list should be moving accordingly. Seems, I am not able to set contentItem correctly. Looking for some hints.

Please find my sample core below, thereupon I added a vertical scrollbar to listView.rolesListModel is my model.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
Window {
width: 400
height: 300
visible: true

    ListModel
    {
        id:rolesListModel
        ListElement
          {
            t:"One"
        }
        ListElement
                      {
            t:"Two"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Three"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Five"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Six"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Seven"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Eight"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Nine"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Ten"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: 150
        height: 100
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        model: rolesListModel
        clip: true
        delegate: listRect

        ScrollBar {
            id: vbar
            active: true
            orientation: Qt.Vertical
            size: listView.height / listView.contentHeight
            position: listView.currentItem
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }
    Component
    {
        id:listRect
        Rectangle
        {
            id:listElementRect
            height:20
            width: 100
            Text
            {
                id:elementText
                width:parent.width
                height:parent.height
                text:t
                horizontalAlignment: "AlignHCenter"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Newer way

You're using an older version of QML, QtQuick is now at 2.14. If you were okay moving from `ScrollBar` to a `ScrollView`, then the code for an arbitrary ListView would look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Scroll")

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

        ListView {
            width: parent.width
            model: 20
            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                text: "Item " + (index + 1)
                width: parent.width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the essential scrollbar configuration line `ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html#scroll-bars

---

## Older way

If, however, you would like to continue with your code, then the fix is to specifically declare that the vertical scrollbar property is bound to your scrollbar

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 300
    visible: true

    ListModel
    {
        id:rolesListModel
        ListElement
        {
            t:"One"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Two"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Three"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Five"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Six"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Seven"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Eight"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Nine"
        }
        ListElement
        {
            t:"Ten"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: 150
        height: 100
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        model: rolesListModel
        clip: true
        delegate: listRect

        ScrollBar.vertical: vbar

        ScrollBar {
            id: vbar
            active: true
            orientation: Qt.Vertical
            size: listView.height / listView.contentHeight
            position: listView.currentItem
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }

    Component
    {
        id:listRect
        Rectangle
        {
            id:listElementRect
            height:20
            width: 100
            Text
            {
                id:elementText
                width:parent.width
                height:parent.height
                text:t
                horizontalAlignment: "AlignHCenter"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Please note the crucial `ScrollBar.vertical: vbar` line, which assigns your ScrollBar component `vbar` to the ListView.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#details

Comment: One small issue still I have with older way, size of scroll bar is coming very small. I tried multiple combination to change the size but none of my trials being reflected. Please note my new list contains 1028 item. My trials are: 1). size: truncatedlist.contentHeight 2). size: runcatedlist.height / truncatedlist.contentHeight)+500 3). size:100